# Django model for variable type of data

Tags: python, database, django, database-design, model

What I am trying to do is a database to keep track of personal records.
The model is almost done, but I'm facing some dificult to store diferent types of records.

There are records for time, for weight, for repetitions/laps, distance... So, there are diferent types of data: time, decimal, integer...

At first I created a table (or class in django) for each type of data. A table to time, other to weight (decimal) and so on.

But I am wonder if there is a better solution to keep only one table for all records.

My code for separated tables/models (so, I have one class for each type, a total of 5 models): (this works well, but I have to pre select the apropriate model to insert data.)

```
class PRWeight(model.Models):  # there are PRDistance, PRLaps, PRHeight, PRTime
    user = FK(User)
    exercise = FK(Exercise)
    date = datefield()
    weight = decimalfield()  # integer, integer, decimal, time

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [user, exercise, date,]
```

Or I can do something like this, and if its a good or there is a better solution:

```
class PR(models.Model):
    user = FK(User)
    exercise = FK(Exercise)
    date = datefield()
    metric = FK(Metric)  # choose between time, weight, height...
                         # the aspect beeing mesured
    record =             # how can I call the right field type?
```

or I can repalce the field "record" for other five fields with blank=True

```
class PR(models.Model):
    user = FK(User)
    exercise = FK(Exercise)
    date = datefield()
    metric = FK(Metric)  # choose between time, weight, height, distance...
                         # the aspect beeing mesured
                         # not necessary in this approach
    wheight = decimalfield(blank=True)
    height = decimalfield(blank=True)
    time = timefield(blank=True)
    distance = integerfield(blank=True)
    laps = integerfield(blank=True)
```

I am looking for a simple solution. So far I'm prone to choose the last example, because it is straight forward, but the user, who will fill the form, can do mistakes...

Comment: Create an abstract model holding all similar data, then seperate your per model specific data to each one of it.
You can either use Abastract Models or table inheritance it's up to your applications logic to define which is the best way.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about tables unless you are working directly into database. Django has a very nice ORM and the main aspect of ORM is that you don't have to look into the database and how it is stored. Just create a nice class hierarchy to access all your items and models and let the ORM decide how much table it needs to save them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table contains the rows that make some statement (parameterized by column names) true. A table should only have columns as long as you can make a single statement using them.

**Put many but related columns together**

If a (user,exercise,date) always has a weight and a date, have a single table.

```
-- user [user] in exercise [exercise] on [date] weighed [weight] kg and was [height] m tall
PRstuff(user,exercise,date,weight,height)
```

But if a (user,exercise,date) might have a weight but not a date, have separate tables.

```
-- user [user] in exercise [exercise] on [date] lifted [weight] kg
PRlift(user,exercise,date,weight)
-- User [user] in exercise [exercise] on [date] jumped [height] m
PRjump(user,exercise,date,height)
```

**Conditional columns are complicated**

It is possible to have a statement/table like your third example:

```
--     user [user] did [exercise] on [date]
-- AND ( lifted != blank and they lifted [weight] kg OR lifted = blank and they didn't lift )
-- AND ( jumped != blank and they jumped [height] m OR jumped = blank and they didn't jump )
PR(user,exercise,date,weight,height)
```

But as you can see your query statements, which are combinations of the table statements, and your SQL expressions, which are combinations of the tables, become complicated. Basically, in querying you have to constantly cut up this table into the separate non-conditional table versions anyway.

**Don't use record-typed columns**

Sometimes we could have a column whose type is made of fixed parts. But if you want to query about the parts using logical conditions like in SQL then instead you should make the parts into columns of the table.

```
-- user [user] in exercise [exercise] on [date] weighed [record.weight] kg and was [record.height] m tall
PRrecord(user,exercise,date,record)

SELECT * FROM PRrecord
WHERE PRrecord.record.weight = 100 -- really, record_dot(PRrecord.record,'weight')=100
```

Here the first dot is a database table operation but the second dot is a programming language record operation. The DBMS cannot optimize your query because it optimizes table operations, not data type operations. Basically it has to get a whole bunch of rows not looking at record values then call record operator dot then call field equality then throw away lots of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM PR
WHERE PR.weight = 100
```

Now the DBMS can combine field equality into how it optimizes getting rows because you have only used the table versions of dot.

**Don't use container-typed columns**

Sometimes we could have a column whose type is made of a collection of similar parts. But if you want to query about the parts using logical conditons like in SQL then instead you should make a new table. The new table has a PK column for that particular collection and the old table has a column that is a FK to the new PK.

```
-- user [user] in exercise [exercise] on [date] and their set of lifted weights in kg is [weights]
PRlifts(user,exercise,date,weights)

SELECT user FROM PRlifts l
WHERE l.name = 'Fred' AND set_has_member(l.weights,200)
AND ??? no two lifts were the same weight ???
```

Bad. Notice how the statement is complicated. Also the DBMS cannot optimize queries because set_has_member is not a table operation. Worse you cannot even query for some conditions, you have to write non-query loop code.

```
SELECT user FROM PRlift l
WHERE l.user = 'Fred' AND l.weight = 200
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT weight
    FROM Prlift l1, PRlift l2
    WHERE l1.user = l.user AND l2.user = l.user AND l1.weight = l2.weight
)
```

Now the DBMS can optimize and also obviate loops.

(Notice that if this were

```
WHERE string_length(l1.name) = string_length(l2.name)
```

then the DBMS could optimize further by having a name length column. But usually a DBMS has special knowledge of strings and certain other types and more or less optimizes as if certain columns existed corresponding to values for certain operators. In fact a DBMS could know about record and set types, but you still couldn't have simple statements and query looplessly.)