# how to design: users with different roles see different records

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rbac

I have a schema design question for my application, hope I can get advices from teachers. This is very alike of Role Based Access Controll, but a bit different in detail.

Spec: 
For one company, there are 4 roles: Company (Boss) / Department (Manager) / Team (Leader) / Member (Sales), and  there are about 1 million Customers records. Each customer record can be owned by someone, and he could be Boss or Manager or Leader or Sales. If the record's owner is some Sales, then his upper grade (say: his leader / manager / boss) can see this record as well (but others: say the same level of his workmates, cannot see, unless his upper grade manager share the customer to his workmates), but if the record's owner is boss, none except the boss himself can see it.

My Design is like this (I want to improve it to make it more simple and clear): 
Table: 
***departments***: 
**id** (P.K. deparment id) 
**d_name** (department name) 
**p_id** (parent department id)

***employees*** 
**id** (P.K. employee id) 
**e_name** (employee name)

***employee_roles*** 
**id** (P.K.) 
**e_id** (employee id) 
**d_id** (department id)

***customers*** 
**id** (P.K. customer id) 
**c_name** (customer name) 
**c_phone** (customer phone)

***permissions*** 
**id** (P.K.) 
**c_id** (customer id) 
**e_id** (owner employee id) 
**d_id** (this customer belongs to which deparment) 
**share_to** (this customer share to other's id)

P.S.: each employee can have multi roles, for example, employee A can be the manager of department_I and meanwhile he can also be one sales of deparment_II >> Team_X.

So, when an employee login to application, by querying from **employee_roles** table, we can get all of the department ids and sub department ids, and save them into an array. 
Then I can use this array to query from **permissions** table and join it with **customers** table to get all the customers this employee should see. The SQL might look like this:

- SELECT * FROM customers AS a INNER JOIN permissions AS b ON a.id =
  b.c_id AND (b.d_id IN ${DEP_ARRAY} OR e_id = ${LOGIN_EMPLOYEE_ID} OR
  share_to = ${LOGIN_EMPLOYEE_ID})

I don't really like the above SQL, especially the "IN" clause, since I am afraid it will slow down the query, since there are about 1 million records or even more in the **customer** table; and, there will be as many records as the **customers** table in the **permissions** table, the **INNER JOIN** might be very slow too. (So what I care about is the performance like everyone :))

To my best knowledge, this is the best design I can work out, could you teachers please help to give me some advice on this question? If you need anything more info, please let me know.
Any advice would be appreciated!
Thanks a million in advance!!

Comment: Do not use an array, use a table, ie the value of a select statement. And stop worrying about performance until you know more basics about thinking in terms of tables and queries.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks a lot for giving me comment. As your advice, use table and avoid using an array, I will try that. I have less experience about joining on large datasets so I was worrying about the performance if I really do it like this. OK, umm.. it seems that you don't think my proposal is too bad :), right? Thanks again, -Wenbin

Comment: Here's a row: (i,c,e,d,s). Under what conditions should I put it in permissions vs leaving it out? Eg "employee [e] has permission to see customer [c]'s ..." ???

Comment: Say: employee X is a manager of department: namely A(id:1), and dep A has one team AT(id:2), and AT has a sub node: SALEs [id:3], in this case, if X login, he has 3 department ids in ***employee_roles*** table: 1 & 2 & 3. So for your question: if [d] in {1,2,3} or if [e] == X's employee id or [s] == X's employee id, then X can see this record. If this is not clear enough, I'd like to describe more.

Comment: Finish/correct the fill-in-the-blanks statement so that when I plug in a (id,c_id,e_id,d_d,share_to) row I get a statement that is true and the row goes in or false and it doesn't. I don't need to know anything else than that statement to use the table, and I can't use the table without it! Also: I fixed a link in my answer. And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097) but think SQL not algebra.

Comment: You should probably use MariaDB since it does roles and users, unlike MySQL which only does users

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, Thanks for your comment. The user / roles I mentioned is not the Database User / Roles, by reading your comments, it seems that you're talking about the user and roles for database of MariaDB. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use an array, use a table, ie the value of a select statement. And stop worrying about performance until you know more basics about thinking in terms of tables and queries.

The point of the relational model is that if you structure your data as tables then you can looplessly describe the output table and the DBMS figures out how to calculate it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24130834/3404097). Do not think about "joining"; think about describing the result. Whatever the DBMS ends up doing is its business not yours. Only after you become knowledgeable about variations in descriptions and options for descriptions will you have basic knowledge to learn about performance.

Comment: Thank you. Per your advice, I think I need to change the **d_id** in ***employee_roles*** table to contain all of the employee's department id and sub ids. Then SQL might look like this: SELECT * FROM customers AS a INNER JOIN permissions AS b, **employee_roles AS c** ON a.id = b.c_id AND **b.d_id = c.d_id** AND (e_id = ${LOGIN_EMPLOYEE_ID} OR share_to = ${LOGIN_EMPLOYEE_ID}). -- I will try and report back. BTW, vote up for not only help me about question, but also teaching me how to make things clear/simple (Whatever the DBMS ends up doing is its business not yours). Thanks:)